# Rails remove attributes from instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
  def edit
    @konkurrencer = Konkurrencer.find(params[:id])
    @konkurrencer.attributes.map{|d| d.map{|d| d.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") } }
  end
```

I want to remove created_at and updated_at attributes for @konkurrencer because I cannot call force_encoding on a time format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this instead of removing those attributes:

```
@konkurrencer.attributes.map{|d| d.map{|d| d.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") if d.respond_to?(:force_encoding) }
```

That will also skip any other attributes you have that don't respond to force_encoding. This results in a big string of nils, though, so I think something you're doing isn't right here...

Comment: what about nested attributes? konkurrencer belongs to photo.

Comment: If the attribute doesn't respond to force_encoding, it won't be included. So only the stuff that can actually be force_encoded will be coerced.

Comment: There is a typo } just behind the if

Answer (score 1):

You can test the type of the attribute and call force_encoding only if it is a String.
Try to change the segment that is like

```
d.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

with

```
(d.is_a? String) ? d.dup.force_encoding('UTF-8') : d.dup
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@konkurrencer.attributes.except(:created_at, :updated_at).map{|d| d.map{|d| d.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") } }
```